# asynchronous decorator for tornado fails

Tags: python, tornado

I am using tornado 3.2 on python 2.7 and the asynchronous decorator is throwing errors. The error is :

```
[~code]$ python server.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File  "server.py", line 15, in <module>
class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
File "server.py", line 16, in UploadHandler
@asynchronous
NameError: name 'asynchronous' is not defined
```

And this is my code that uses decorator:

```
class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def post(self):
      print "In post"
      self.redirect("/upload.html")
```

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the fully qualified name:

```
class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def post(self):
        print("In post")
        self.redirect("/upload.html")
```

Alternatively, you could import all of `tornado.web` to use the single name:

```
from tornado.web import *
```